# Allow radio button to be checked only once to select its unique value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I have "n" number of rows being returned by an SQL statement. It works fine. For every row returned, I like the user to pick an option (Pass=1, Fail=2, NA=3) and insert these values (1, 2, 3) into a DB table when submit.

However, I run into problems when I attempt to get the value of the radio button the user has selected, as well as other values, like CategoryID or SubcatID.

The dynamic HTML form is like this:

[image]

```
Category table
CategoryID   Category
------------
01      cat
02      cat 2
03      cat 3

Subcat table
SubcatID   Subcat   Category_id
-------------------------
1       Jenny     01
2       Emmy      01
3       James      02
4       Hudson     02
5       Mike      03
```

Report table output should be:

```
ReportID   CategoryID   SubcatID   Scale
------------------------------------------
1          01           1          1
2          01           2          1
3          02           3          2
4          02           4          2
5          03           5          3
```

In other words, each time when I submit the form, there will be 5 records inserted into a table. If I add another subcategory into a main category, then there will be 6 records added into a table.

Currently, the Report table show this, which is wrong:

```
ReportID   CategoryID   SubcatID   Scale
------------------------------------------
1      01, 02, 03   1, 2, 3, 4, 5   empty
```

Here is my ASP Code:

```
If Request.Form("FormSource") = "SubmitForm" Then
   sReportID = Request.Form("ReportID")
   sCategoryID = Request.Form("CategoryID")
   sSubcatID = Request.Form("SubcatID")
   sScale = Request.Form("Scale")

SQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON;" &_
    "INSERT INTO Report (ReportID, CategoryID, SubcatID, Scale) VALUES " &_
    "('" & SCategoryID & "', '" & SSubcatID & "', '" & SCategoryID & "', '" & SScale & "');" &_
    "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ReportID"
Set  objRS = objCon.Execute (SQL)
    sReportID = objRS.Fields("ReportID").value
objRS.Close
End If
%>

<form action="" method="post" id="newCategory">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Category and sub</td>
<td>Pass</td>
<td>Fail</td>
<td>NA</td>
</tr>

<%
  currCat = ""
  sSQL = "SELECT s.*, c.* FROM Category c, Subcat s WHERE s.Subcat_id = c.Subcat_id "
  objRS.Open sSQL, objCon
  response.Write sSQL
  Do Until objRS.EOF
    sCategory = objRS("Category")
    sSubcat = objRS("Subcat")

    if currCat <> sCategory Then
       currCat = sCategory 
    %>
<tr><td><%=sCategory%></td></tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="CategoryID" size="40" maxlength="50" value="<%=sCategory%>">
       <%
    End If
    %>
<tr><td><%= sSubcat %></td>
      <input type="hidden" name="SubcatID" size="40" maxlength="50" value="<%= sSubcat %>">
    <td><input size="20" type="radio" name="<%=sCategory%>" value="1"></td>
    <td><input size="20" type="radio" name="<%=sCategory%>" value="2"></td>
    <td><input size="20" type="radio" name="<%=sCategory%>" value="3"></td>
</tr>
<%
    objRS.MoveNext
  Loop

   objRS.Close
%>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="FormSource" value="CatSubmit">
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="submitForm();">
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I was able to figure out how to select each Radio button by adding <%=sCategory%> on Name in each INPUT box. I don't know why I got '0' for all fields even I checked different boxes. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed up some of the code in your question. If you managed to solve your question, I'd advise you post an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I still can't get it worked. I got a correct ReportID output. However, Scale is empty value. CatID: 2, 5, 7 and Subcate ID: 1,2,3. They are supposed to be one unique ID per row. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code you're now using?

Comment: BoffinbraiN, I updated my question. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is name your radio button groups using `SubcatID` instead of `CategoryID`, since the subcat is what's unique about each row in your table. Using the categoryID will cause multiple radio button values to get clumped up together, separated with commas, as you found out.

You can give your inputs a name such as `subcatX` where X is the actual SubcatID for that row. For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="subcat<%= sSubcat %>" value="1">
```

When you load the page to process the form data, you will know which Subcats you are interested in, and iterate over them to look for the presence of form data associated with it. The pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
(for all subcatIDs you care about)
    val = Request.Form("subcat" & subcatID)
    If val <> "" Then
       ...
```

PS. Your radio buttons don't need a `size` attribute, and your hidden form fields don't need `size` or `maxlength`.

**Additional info: how to find your form fields by iterating over `Request.Form`**

This snippet of code should help you discover exactly what you're posting back so you can analyse it and get the correct subcat IDs out. You don't even need to know the names of your fiends in advance if you do it this way, since you can just iterate over all of them and check if they match your pattern.

```
    <%
        Dim i, key, val
        For Each i In Request.Form
            key = Request.Form.Key(i)
            val = Request.Form.Item(i)
            Response.Write key & " = " & val & "<br>"
        Next
    %>
    <form action="?" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="A" />
        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="B" />
        <input type="hidden" name="c" value="C" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

If you run this by itself, you will find that the output is

```
a = A, B
c = C
```

Notice how both values A and B were strung together automatically because they had the same field name. You want to avoid this.

Comment: I changed name="subcat<% sSubcat %>, the output is the same. I don't understand how to change this: val = Request.Form("subcat" & subcatID). Can you write in more detailed? I don't know how to start and change my code to get it worked. Thanks.

Comment: In your code where you gather the form data: `If Request.Form("FormSource") = "SubmitForm"` you need to change that to look up specific values such as the `Request.Form("subcat" & subcatID)` I wrote. Or, you can iterate over the whole `Request.Form` collection and save each one that way.

Comment: I am new to this. Can you show me how to look up specific values for subcat? In other words, can you write me a block of codes so I can start with others? Thanks.

Comment: @JennyTran I've extended my answer so show how you can look through the values in your form post.

Comment: I tried to change by creating that loop. I replaced key with subcatID, but it sitll didn't work. I changed name="subcat<% sSubcat %>.  It didn't work. How do I inbox you?

Comment: You can't replace `key` while in the loop. It's crucial to know what that value is, since it pertains to the data that was posted. You need to look at `key`, determine if it looks like a subcatID and then use `val` to save the data to the database. Without writing the whole thing myself, it's hard to help any more than that.